# Asp.net MVC RegularExpression Validator whose error message depends on another property in the Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model property which is of type double with two decimal points allowed, I have used the following attribute to ensure this

```
[RegularExpression(RegularExpressionHelper.PositiveTwoDecimalNumberExpression, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Account balance")]
public double AccountBalance { get; set; }
```

there is another model property say,

```
public bool IsSavingsAccount { get; set; }
```

Now the behavior i need is wheneever IsSavingsAccount is true the message for invalid account balance should be "Invalid Savings Account Balance" else it should be "Invalid Current Account Balance".The Other property type happens to be a boolean here but it could be anything so i am looking for a solution which can accommodate this.

Is it necessary to write a custom validator to achieve this ? if yes how to go about it ?

Comment: [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have a number of validation attributes such as `[RequiredIfTrue]` that should suit your needs

Comment: At this point in time I would like to either use out of the box validation or write something myself as this is the only special case I have, so from your comment, custom validator seems to be the way is it ?

Comment: Yes, you can write your own attributes. You derive from `ValidationAttribute` and implement `IClientValidatable`, then write scripts for `$.validator.addMethod` and `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a custom validation attribute that inherits from RegularExpressionAttribute, and use the validation context to check the other property:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class PositiveTwoDecimalAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public PositiveTwoDecimalAttribute() : base(RegularExpressionHelper.PositiveTwoDecimalNumberExpression) { }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        bool isSavingsAccount = (bool)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("IsSavingsAccount").GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        var errorMessage = isSavingsAccount ? "Invalid Savings Account balance" : "Invalid Current balance";

        if(!base.IsValid(value)){
            return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;

    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new BalanceAmountModelClientValidationRegexRule(this.ErrorMessage, RegularExpressionHelper.PositiveTwoDecimalNumberExpression);
    }
}

 public class BalanceAmountModelClientValidationRegexRule: ModelClientValidationRegexRule
 {

    public BalanceAmountModelClientValidationRegexRule(string errorMessage, string pattern)
        : base(errorMessage, pattern)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll check this out but before i do that another question do i need to implement IClientValidatable to make this work on the client side ?

Comment: Yes I think so, and you register it in global.asax app start also I believe.

Comment: edited above solution to add the code that helped solve my problem, note that i didn't have to do anything on the client side (i.e creating a client side function & adapter) i just reused the existing regex unobtrusive client bits